# Looping thru xml then updating xml variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-dml

My xml looks like the ff:

```
<root>
  <TemplateQuestion>
    <Row rfqID="1" rftID="1" questionDesc="Question 1" responseType="1" rfqDisplayOrder="1" deletedBit="0" />
    <Row rfqID="2" rftID="1" questionDesc="Question 2" responseType="2" rfqDisplayOrder="2" deletedBit="0" />
    <Row rfqID="3" rftID="1" questionDesc="Question 3" responseType="3" rfqDisplayOrder="3" deletedBit="0" />
  </TemplateQuestion>
</root>
```

Now my goal is to make the rfqID to have the letter "q" before it. So the results should be like the ff:

```
<root>
  <TemplateQuestion>
    <Row rfqID="q1" rftID="1" questionDesc="Question 1" responseType="1" rfqDisplayOrder="1" deletedBit="0" />
    <Row rfqID="q2" rftID="1" questionDesc="Question 2" responseType="2" rfqDisplayOrder="2" deletedBit="0" />
    <Row rfqID="q3" rftID="1" questionDesc="Question 3" responseType="3" rfqDisplayOrder="3" deletedBit="0" />
  </TemplateQuestion>
</root>
```

I am achieving that by doing this:

```
    declare @xml XML
    set @xml = (select dbo.udfGetXMLVal(1))

    declare @nodeCount int
    declare @i int
    declare @qid nvarchar(20)

    set @i = 1
    select @nodeCount = @xml.value('count(/root/TemplateQuestion/Row/@rfqID)','int')
    while(@i <= @nodeCount)
    begin
    select @qid = x.value('@rfqID[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') 
    from @xml.nodes('/root/TemplateQuestion/Row[position()=sql:variable("@i")]') e(x)
    set @qid = 'q' + @qid
    select @qid

    Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/TemplateQuestion/Row/@rfqID)[1] with sql:variable("@qid")')

    set @i = @i + 1 
end
```

Im having problems with this line:

```
Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/TemplateQuestion/Row/@rfqID)[1] with sql:variable("@qid")')
```

How can I replace the [1] to the variable @i? I get some error with string literals when I try to use sql:variable.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hi Aedz Migraso. It is perfectly OK that you accepted har07's answer as it exactly answered your question. There's only one tiny hint I'd like to give you for future issues: avoid loops (google about RBAR, procedural thinking and row based / set based thinking)!

Comment: you need to do formatting in your answer according TSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"How can I replace the `[1]` to the variable `@i`? I get some error with string literals when I try to use `sql:variable`"*

You can do it like this (tested and works in SQL Server 2008R2) :

```
Set @xml.modify('
    replace value of ((/root/TemplateQuestion/Row/@rfqID)[sql:variable("@i")] )[1]
    with sql:variable("@qid")
')
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty :-)

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CAST(@x AS VARCHAR(MAX)),' rftID="',' rftID="q')  AS XML);
```

And here's a clean approach:

```
DECLARE @x  XML='<root>
  <TemplateQuestion>
    <Row rfqID="1" rftID="1" questionDesc="Question 1" responseType="1" rfqDisplayOrder="1" deletedBit="0" />
    <Row rfqID="2" rftID="1" questionDesc="Question 2" responseType="2" rfqDisplayOrder="2" deletedBit="0" />
    <Row rfqID="3" rftID="1" questionDesc="Question 3" responseType="3" rfqDisplayOrder="3" deletedBit="0" />
  </TemplateQuestion>
</root>';

SELECT
(
    SELECT 'q' + R.value('@rfqID','varchar(max)') AS [@rfqID]
          ,R.value('@rftID','int') AS [@rftID]
          ,R.value('@questionDesc','varchar(max)') AS [@questionDesc]
          --other attributes similar    
    FROM @x.nodes('/root/TemplateQuestion/Row') AS A(R)
    FOR XML PATH('Row'),ROOT('TemplateQuestion'),TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('root');
```